# How to show skeleton loading until image has rendered completely?

Tags: html, image, react-loading-skeleton

[image]

I'm using [react-loading-skeleton](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-skeleton) and this is my code (simplified):

```
const [image, setImage] = useState("");

const { isLoading } = useQuery(
    ["getImage"],
        async () => {
            await axios.get(someurl).then(res => {
                let theimage = res.data.image;
                if (theimage != "" && theimage != null) {
                    setImage(theimage)
                }
            })
        }
    );

return (
    <>{showLoading ? <Skeleton /> : <img src={image} />}</>
)
```

The problem is the gap (jump, shift, ...) when switching from skeleton to image.
Look at the text. It changes from "loading" to "loaded!" as soon as `imageFromState` is loaded, but it takes time to show the image.

Is there a way to see if the image had **loaded & rendered** completely and only switch from skeleton to image after that?

(I know I can set a default image src and give the container a fixed height so it doesn't move, but I want to show the skeleton animation until the image is fully visible)

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: @knoefel nope 